# Updating/Saving job post in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I followed my  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29498775/saving-updating-user-profile-in-laravel-5) to do the same with my job post but I'm getting a blank view (blank browser) when I hit the update button.

**Controller**

```php
public function edit($id)
{
    $job = Job::whereId($id)->firstOrFail();

    return view('jobs.edit')->withJob($job);
}

public function update($id)
{
    $job = Job::whereId($id)->firstOrFail();
    $job->fill(Input::all());
    $job->save();

    flash('You have successfully edited your Job Post');

    return redirect('/jobs'.$id);
}
```

**Edit View**

```php
{!! Form::model($job, array('method' => 'PATCH', 'route' =>array('jobs.update', $job->id))) !!}
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('job_title', 'Title') !!}
    {!! Form::text('job_title', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('job_description', 'Description') !!}
    {!! Form::text('job_description', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
</div>
{!! Form::submit('Update Job Post!', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Route**

```php
Route::resource('jobs', 'JobsController');
```

An extra eye and clear brain would help me with why my edit does not work.

Comment: `return redirect('/jobs' . $id);` this looks wrong to me. are you sure such path  like "/jobs4" exist? also you could do `Job::findOrFail($id)` instead of `Job::whereId($id)->firstOrFail();`

Comment: @ConradWarhol Thanks for that but if it worked that I'd get some page not found but that didnt solved it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your own provided answer is correct, however to clear up the point for future readers, I will answer the question as to why.

Any class that has a namespace, requires that you access the facades via their namespace, which is simply `\`. So if your class, say a controller or model, starts with `<? namespace Acme\Boxes;` then all facades references need to be namespaced too, such as `\Input::get()`.

However if you are not in a namespaced class, such as a view, you don't need to use the namespaced version of a facade. However try not to litter your views with facades.

Finally, if you really dislike having `\Input` and `\Config` everywhere, you can add a use statement at the top of your class. Such as

```
use \Input as Input;
use \Config as Config;

// ... somewhere else in this class ...//
Input::get('bla');
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Change Your Update Function to the following-

```
  public function update($id)
{
    $job =  \App\User::whereId($id)->firstOrFail();
    $job->fill(\Input::all());
    $job->save();

    flash('You have successfully edited your Job Post');

    return redirect('/');
}
```

Hope it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

It's weird as few parts in my app I have to use `\Input` and other I only use `Input`. For this case, this solves the answer: `$job->fill(\Input::all());`