# laravel update registered user

Tags: php, laravel

I have recently started working in Laravel, my first `Framework`. I have experience with `PHP` but I am a little lost now.

I used the default `auth` that comes with laravel. But I am trying to make a function to edit the users that have registered.

I dont quite see how the data gets to the database from the form.

My form: (didn't put all inputs)

```
@isset($user)
<form method="POST" action="{{ WHAT GOES HERE?? }}">
@csrf
{{--name--}}
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Name') }}</label>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="name" value="{{ $user->name }}" required autofocus>
    </div>
</div>

{--last name--}}
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="lastname"
           class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Last Name') }}</label>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="lastname" type="text"
               class="form-control{{ $errors->has('lastname') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="lastname" value="{{ $user->lastname }}" required autofocus>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row mb-0">
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            {{ __('Edit user') }}
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I did not make a route yet, as I do not know how exactly. Or if this is even needed.

My controller:

```
public function edit_profile($userId, Request $request)
    {
        $this->isAllowed($userId, true);
        $userProfile = User::findOrFail((int)$userId);


        //TODO validation
        //TODO update user model + save to db

        $userProfile->update();

        return view('user/edit_profile', [
            /* $ */
            'user' => $userProfile,
        ]);
    }
```

As stated; I do know what needs to happen. I just don't know and understand how.

And last, my user.php

```
protected $fillable = [
'name',
'lastname',
'email',
'password',
'mobile_number',
'date_of_birth',
];
```

My next step would be to make a route, to get the data to the controller. But I don't see how this route would look.

Comment: For form `action` you have to create a route on which the form submit, and that route is mapped with a controller function, in this function write the logic to update the user details using user model.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving/Updating User Profile in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29498775/saving-updating-user-profile-in-laravel-5)

Comment: The dabatase is specified in your environment file `.env`

Comment: @MayankPandeyz What should the uri of the route be?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a Route for your action.
Go to `routes->web.php`(laravel 5.3 or above) and add your route structure.

```
Route::http-verb('url name',"Controller name@Controller Method name");
```

This is the route you have to add in your web.php file

```
Route::post('edit-profile', 'ProfileController@edit_profile');
```

I am assuming that you have a controller with name as `ProfileController` and inside you have `edit_profile` method.

```
{{ url('/edit-profile') }}
```

add above code to action attribute.

If you are using laravel 5.2 or old version the routes configuration resides inside `app/Http/routes.php`.

Comment: Should this route not be a POST? As my form is also a post form?

Comment: Yes. It depends on your form method or http verb.